# Read the fist input character using "Scanner" and "charAt(0)" through the "For" loop in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to obtain the first character by providing a word.

e.g.

Enter a word: apple

The first character is "a"

Enter a world: banana

The first character is "b"

When I execute the code (provided below), the first loop provides the correct result with `charAt(0)` but the consequences of next loops would gives the "Empty" character. (i.e. I get correct result by applying `charAt(1)`)

I have no clue what this empty character is (new line? tab? white space?) and do not no how to remove this one.

And it would be unnecessary to declare every Scanner field repeatedly inside the loop.

P.S. I have tried with applying delimiter (e.g. `useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator())` or remove the leading & tailing spaces (e.g. `trim()`) but the result would be the same.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadCharacter {

    // Declare the scanner field
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter character
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
            char character = input.next().charAt(0);    

            // Show the result
            System.out.println("The first character is \"" + character + "\"\n");           
        }

    }

}
```

Expected result

Enter a word: apple

The first character is "a"

Enter a word: banana

The first character is "b"

Enter a word: orange

The first character is "o"

....

Actual Result

Enter a word: apple

The first character is "a"

Enter a word: banana

The first character is ""

Enter a word: orange

The first character is ""

....

Comment: use [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead of [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. I get your expected result...

Comment: You are right. Since I am using Eclipse IDE, I removed whole Java project folder (package, source code etc) and re-produced the fresh Java project with same code....and it seems working fine.....hmm....Interesting.... But thanks guys for confirming this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code. The most parts work properly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //change in this answer
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter character
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        char character = input.next().charAt(0);

        // Show the result
        System.out.println("The first character is \"" + character + "\"\n");
    }

}
```

**Result :**

```
Enter a word: apple
The first character is "a"

Enter a word: orange
The first character is "o"

Enter a word: banana
The first character is "b"

Enter a word: nothing
The first character is "n"

Enter a word: wrong
The first character is "w"
```

Comment: A comment would have sufficed.

Comment: Are you serious? XD  There is a change at least

Comment: "I tried your code. It works properly." to me implies that you didn't modify the code, so I didn't even look. If you did, please mention it and point it out. *Then* it can be considered an actual answer.

Comment: Uhm, not really :( I mean, if there's no problem in the code and you just move it to `main` instead of a function, why post an answer at all? Look, I'm one in hundreds of thousands of users. If my downvote is not warranted and your answer deserves an upvote, someone will surely give you one. Don't fret over a single downvote :)

Comment: XD, yeah it makes sense.

Comment: As a Eclipse user myself, this IDE would makes the suggestion to convert the local variable (i.e. Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) into the field (i.e.private static Scanner input ......input = new Scanner(System.in);)...Anyway, I removed my old Java file and re-create new fresh java project file with "old code" and the code seem to be working fine as expected (weird, but I have no clue).....but thank you guys for the suggestion.